# intractable iframe embed - won't play nicely

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

I've tried every combination of properties and attributes I can think of to get this iframe to embed in a WordPress post so that all of it is visible on both mobile and large screens. It seems I need to specify a height to get the whole frame to display, but doing so then stops all the width showing on mobile.

Any help much appreciated.

```
<div markdown="0" id="island">
  <iframe style="width: 100%; border: none" scrolling="no" src="http://devonmathstuition.co.uk/dev/treasure-island/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your iframe inside another element (with it's position `relative`), and place your iframe with an `absolute` position:

The padding-top: 56.25% is useful for keeping the ratio (16:9) of the iframe.

Working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1csevy6/) (try resizing the display tab :)).

Html:

```html
<section>
    <article id="iframe">
        <iframe src="src.html"></iframe>
    </article>
</section>
```

Css:

```css
section{
    max-width: 800px;
}

#iframe{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}

iframe{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

src: [smashingmagazine.com](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/)

edit: [here's a video](https://up.l3m.in/file/1561706303-iframe-example.webm) of a resizeable iframe :)

edit2: oopps, forgot a `section` tag

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work - it cuts of the iframe at about half its height.

Comment: oops, I forgot the section element (and its css), edited my answer :)

Comment: I just looked at your iframe. You need to change the `padding-top` value to `100%` to make it appear correctly (your iframe don't have a 16:9 ratio) :)

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't work on mobile - just shows part of frame.

Comment: All your positions are fixed on your page. You need to position your elements with %age or vh. I tested some things and here is your page : [video](https://up.l3m.in/file/1561886313-treasure-island.webm).